# GPU Image Framework X-ray Effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, gpuimage

[image]I am making a application that you can apply different effects to photos using GPU Image Framework by Brad Larson.I want to add X-ray Effect filter in GPU image app.Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: What is an "X-ray effect"? What does that look like? We can't help you until you show us an image or some other details of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like the GPUImageColorInvertFilter:

[image: Color invert filter]

If that doesn't produce the exact effect you want, you could create a custom filter based on it and have your fragment shader first convert to luminance, and then apply a greenish tint based on the inverse of the pixel's luminance. That would provide the exact effect you show above.

I'll leave the coding of such a shader as an exercise for the reader.